# How to position an element at the TOP LEFT corner of a page using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to place div id="wrapper" on the TOP LEFT corner of the page (top and left = 0), like the id="test" div.
Could you point me out what is wrong with my code?

For your vision:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9fzX/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li class="focus">0</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>15</li>
            <li>16</li>
            <li>17</li>
            <li>18</li>
            <li>19</li>
            <li>20</li>
            <li>21</li>
            <li>22</li>
            <li>23</li>
            <li>24</li>
            <li>25</li>
            <li>26</li>
            <li>27</li>
            <li>28</li>
            <li>29</li>
            <li>30</li>
            <li>31</li>
            <li>32</li>
            <li>33</li>
            <li>34</li>
            <li>35</li>
            <li>36</li>
            <li>37</li>
            <li>38</li>
            <li>39</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigator">
    <div id="up" class="btn">UP</div>
    <div id="down" class="btn">DOWN</div>
    <div id="left" class="btn">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right" class="btn">RIGHT</div>
    <div id="pageinfo" class="pageinfo">Page 1 of tot 4</div>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

And the css :

```
#test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 600px;
}
#navigator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 600px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #d80000;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
.focus {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
.btn {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px gray solid;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? When I give `#wrapper` a green background, it shows up on the left top of the page...?

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Comment: Also I realise this CSS is only for problem solving purposes, but `!important` should never really be necessary in a well written set of CSS, as soon as you start down the !important path it soon becomes impossible to style without !important, bringing you back to the original problem that the styles should just be organised enough to properly cascade (there are framework exceptions of course, like AngularJS, but only in rare and extreme cases). It just makes code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your CSS actually already was correct, but each browser has default styling which includes default margin and padding. This is what was causing your elements to be positioned strangely.

Adding the following "reset" CSS at the top fixed it:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9fzX/3/)

Comment: You could do `*, body{margin:0;padding:0;}` instead of having both.

Comment: He has already set margin: 0; padding: 0; in body and for position fixed its not valued.

Comment: @BeatAlex the `body` part can be removed completely, as `*` already includes the body.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this css, because your ul element takes default margin and padding.

```
ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
```

This is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/bWDCJ/)

Comment: @C-Link no, OP wants his `#wrapper` to be top-left. The `#test` div was an example to show what he wants.

Comment: @C-Link, Don't comment without understanding any question and answer