# How do I make a chrome extension appear in the left side of the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, popup

I was searching many different website to see how I can position my HTML popup into the left side of the website, but many of them didn't work. My popup was stuck in the default element, such as when you create a normal popup and a window appears with a arrow above it. Is there any way to make the popup appear hovering the website while its on the left side of the screen?

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#popupContainer{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="popupContainer">
    <p>Popup content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position an element at the TOP LEFT corner of a page using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694439/how-to-position-an-element-at-the-top-left-corner-of-a-page-using-css)

Comment: use `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` so you can use the `left, right, top or bottom` properties on the element. More clarification would be useful if this doesn't answer your question.